# Apache Ignite: How to cache an entry with multiple keys

Tags: c#, .net, ignite, gridgain

Is there any way to cache one entry against two keys in apache ignite?
say for eg: I need to cache users, based on their user id and their username, so I can get it back in both ways.
Which is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use two caches, from Id to User (`ICache<Guid, User>`) and from UserName to Id `ICache<string, Guid>`
2. Use one cache `ICache<Guid, User>`, and create an SQL index on UserName column https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/indexes

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Is it possible to perform SQL-like queries in Apache Ignite without a database?

Comment: Yes, Ignite IS the database with SQL capabilities, please see the docs (link in the answer) and example: https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/platforms/dotnet/examples/Thick/Sql/Sql/Program.cs